# unable to resolve identifier __PRETTY_FUNCTION__

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have basic cpp file in NetBeans. When I want to use  `"__PRETTY_FUNCTION__"` ,I get this message " `unable to resolve identifier __PRETTY_FUNCTION__`".
How can i resolve that or why i get this error message ? Any ideas ?

Best Regards,Mert.

Comment: what compiler? how about `__func__`

Comment: @BryanChen Im using g++.

Answer (score 2):

It is not `pretty_function` but `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

---

Now you've edited your question, your problem seems to be **[a NetBeans problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8652490/3460805)**.