# Unable to resolve template based identifier "get". Netbeans 8.1

Tags: c++, netbeans, autocomplete, openframeworks

**My problem is:**

I am receiving warning which is presented in the topic of a post.
It is really flustrating. The *autocomplete* does not work with the code, beside which the warning occurs. *The standard is set to **C++14**.*

**For instance:**

```
 Boxes[2].get()->setPosition(Boxes[2].get()->getPosition() + v1);
```

It gives me a warning and when I try to write another `Boxes[2].`the *autocomplete* does not work.

**The declaration of an object:**

```
<shared_ptr<ofxBox2dRect>> Boxes;
```

**I tried to solve my problem using these links:**

1. [Unable to resolve identifier on netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199384/unable-to-resolve-identifier-on-netbeans)
2. [“Unable to resolve identifier” , although build is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913243/netbeans-7-2-shows-unable-to-resolve-identifier-although-build-is-successful)

And much more but they did not help me: (I repearsed the project etc.)

**My NetBeans version is 8.1 and the C++ plugin 1.29.6.1 working on Apricity OS.**

I did some research and I receive some of other warnings as well and I think that they are related with my problem.

**The list of Warnings:**

```
Recursive directive #include <boost/predef/os/bsd.h> 
Analyzed user include paths and user include headers: 
/usr/include 
/usr/lib 
/usr/lib64 
/usr/share 
/usr/src 
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 
/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include 
/usr/include/AL 
/usr/include/alsa 
/usr/include/gtk-3.0 
/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 
/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 
/usr/include/dbus-1.0 
/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include 
/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 
/usr/include/cairo 
/usr/include/pango-1.0 
/usr/include/atk-1.0 
/usr/include/pixman-1 
/usr/include/freetype2 
/usr/include/libpng16 
/usr/include/harfbuzz 
/usr/include/glib-2.0 
/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include 
/usr/include/libdrm 
/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/fmodex/include 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/glfw/include 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/glfw/include/GLFW 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/kiss/include 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/poco/include 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/tess2/include 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/utf8cpp/include 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/utf8cpp/include/utf8 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/graphics 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/math 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/events 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/gl 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/communication 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/video 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/3d 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/utils 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/app 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/sound 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/types 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project 
Analyzed system include paths: 
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1 
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/backward 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/include 
/usr/local/include 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.1.1/include-fixed 
/usr/include 
/home/charllie/of-workspace 
Include path trail to current file: 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/graphics/ofPath.cpp: (line 1) 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/graphics/ofPath.h: (line 6) 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/graphics/ofPolyline.h: (line 5) 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/types/ofRectangle.h: (line 6) 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/utils/ofLog.h: (line 4) 
/home/charllie/of-workspace/libs/openFrameworks/utils/ofFileUtils.h: (line 8) 
/usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp: (line 16) 
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp: (line 29) 
/usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp: (line 17) 
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: (line 35) 
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp: (line 25) 
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock.hpp: (line 50) 
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_sync.hpp: (line 18) 
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/yield_k.hpp: (line 28) 
/usr/include/boost/predef.h: (line 17) 
/usr/include/boost/predef/os.h: (line 18) 
/usr/include/boost/predef/os/bsd.h: (line 52) 
/usr/include/boost/predef/os/bsd/bsdi.h: (line 11) 
/usr/include/boost/predef/os/bsd.h: (line 95) 
/usr/include/boost/predef/os/bsd/dragonfly.h: (line 11) 
/usr/include/boost/predef/os/bsd.h: (line 96) 
Ctrl+Alt+Click to open include hierarchy
```

**In my opinion this warning is the most important:**

```
Library File /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp 
but there is an recursion #include <boost/predef/os/bsd.h> in included /usr/include/boost/predef/os/bsd/free.h 
Use Ctrl+Alt to show analyzed paths Ctrl+Alt+Click to open file with failed include directive
```

I spent couple of hours trying to solve my problem. I followed the steps which are presented in links given above, but they did not help me.
Hope that there I will find help.

**The most important thing for me is to
receive the *autocomplete* fully workable.**

I got the *autocomplete* **ON** and it works fine, but not in this particular case.

I thought that might be a problem with namespaces so add `using namespace std;`
I rebuilt, cleaned and repearsed the project, but it did not help.;(

**Thanks for your help ;)**

Comment: Why is the build including bsd headers ? Apricity is Linux...

Comment: Yes but is always better to specify the distro. bsd is needed by openframeworks ofFileUtils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem.  The issue is with the boost **predef/os/bsd.h** header.  It #includes 5 files in the #else block for the #ifndef  BOOST_PREDEF_OS_BSD_H guard.  This means that this header file is not guarded against recursion if any of those 5 files also includes bsd.h (which they do).

My solution was to edit the predef/os/bsd.h file and add a recursion guard in the #else block - so, starting at around line 94 my predef/os/bsd.h file now looks like:

```
#ifndef BOOST_PREDEF_OS_BSD_H_PREVENT_RECURSION      <-- ADD THIS
#define BOOST_PREDEF_OS_BSD_H_PREVENT_RECURSION      <-- ADD THIS

#include <boost/predef/os/bsd/bsdi.h>
#include <boost/predef/os/bsd/dragonfly.h>
#include <boost/predef/os/bsd/free.h>
#include <boost/predef/os/bsd/open.h>
#include <boost/predef/os/bsd/net.h>

#endif                                               <-- ADD THIS
```

And now netbeans code assistance is happy and my code still links and compiles without error.